# Css text color changing thanks to a (true/false) variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm actually working from this example:
http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/truefalse/index.html

My objective is replacing the "true" or "false" text which displays when you click the question by a simple color change of the question. For example, clicking a right question would change text to green while clicking a false one would change it to red.

I have always found ways to achieve what I wanted with CSS but i'm now totally stuck on this. Any input/hint is appreciated.

Comment: Please add _the relevant_ code to your post.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you write questions, make sure users aren't forced to visit another site to understand and show what you tried.

Comment: And if you're learning the basics, I really suggest you don't use JQuery yet. Learn how JS actually works. [And here's a tip!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Did you see the source code of that page

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Other than the tag, where is JavaScript? `:O`

Comment: @PraveenKumar there is no need for JS, it's using `:active`

Comment: Exactly @ somethinghere! The idea behind this was to not use JS by the way. Thanks for your answers I'm figuring this out myself...

Comment: @PraveenKumar Oh, there indeed is no JS there. I sort of assumed from the tags. Forget about that MDN link then...

Comment: @ [You both] My comment was for Jacque... Not for you guys! LoL.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite simple, and you don't need to use anything other than CSS to accomplish *what you asked in your question*. I didn't fully read the article you linked, but the asked question is simple enough.

What you need is to add a *class* to each statement, one for correct statement, and one for each wrong one. You do this simply with `<div class="someClass">`.

Then, you will use the CSS :active selector, which allows you to style something when that element is being pressed.

So, some final code would be.

```css
.question {
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
}

.true:active {
    color: green;
}

.false:active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="true question"> Some statement here. </div>
<div class="true question"> Another statement. </div>
<div class="false question"> A sketchy statement. </div>
```

Comment: @user1266743, No problem! Don't forget to hit the checkmark if this answered your question.

Comment: id="question" in all div ??? !!

Comment: @hmtareque, Nice catch. It is valid, but of course using classes would be better. I was originally going to only have one element, but ended up copy-pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Click this link [designshack](http://designshack.net/?p=38787)to see the tutorial of the entire solution..There they clearly says about each and every line of that section...

at last ..there is a heading and some note and also shown some bit of codes.

**You have to change this code to get your answer.**

**Using :active to Show The Answer**

```
h2:active ~ .yes {
  color: #ff0000;    //change here and put color:#2D9D08;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

Try it..

Comment: Thanks I tried this!

Comment: Did you get the result

Comment: Aye I'm fine tuning it right now, posting it asap